# Why is the Miplevel calculated using dFdx and dFdy not equal to that queried by textureQueryLod?

Tags: opengl, glsl

According to document "OpenGL4.6(Core Profile)", the miplevel is caculated as following
[image]

I implement this caculation and compare the result with the return value of `textureQueryLod`.

- The codes of calculating miplevel

```c
float calc_mip_level(vec2 ddx, vec2 ddy, ivec2 texture_size)
{
    float rho_x = length(ddx * texture_size.x);
    float rho_y = length(ddy * texture_size.y);
    float rho_max = max(rho_x, rho_y);
    float rho_min = min(rho_x, rho_y);
    float N = min(ceil(rho_max / rho_min), 16);
    return log2(rho_max / N);
}
```

The ddx and ddy parameters is calculated by `ddx = dFdx(uv);ddy = dFdy(uv);`.

- The properties of sampler in renderdoc
  [image]
- The visual result of calculated miplevel

[image]

- The visual result of queried miplevel

[image]

Why is there much difference between the calculated and queried miplevels?